# What is the symbol for a function that is complex differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, notation

Suppose $f:D \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$.

If $f$ is differentiable (or $\mathbb{R}$-differentiable) we say $f \in C^1(D;\mathbb{R}^2)$ or $f \in C^1(D)$ (meaning the partial derivatives exist and they are continuous).

Now if $f:D \subset \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, is it correct to say that $f \in C^1(D;\mathbb{C})$ or $f \in C^1(D)$ if $f$ is $\mathbb{C}$-differentiable (meaning it is $\mathbb{R}$-differentiable as a vector field and the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied).

If it is incorrect, what is the correct symbol for a $\mathbb{C}$-differentiable function $f$?

Comment: I think I've seen $H(\Omega)$ be used for the set of holomorphic (hence $H$) functions on an open set $\Omega$.

Comment: I don't have a source to cite at my fingertips (hence I'm not posting an answer), but $C^1(X)$ typically denotes the set of once-differentiable functions on the domain $X$, where $X$ could be any kind of space where derivatives make sense (e.g. the set of real numbers, an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, some domain $D\subseteq \mathbb{C}$, and so on).  Since having one derivative on $\mathbb{C}$ implies smoothness, $C^{\infty}(X)$ would also be fine (where, again $X$ could be any reasonable set, including a subset of $\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: Unless you want to talk about holomorphic functions on a domain, there is no universal notation that is used.